# Returning 2 arrays from a function

Tags: c#

I create 2 jagged arrays inside my function:

```
double[][] x = new double[i][];
double[][] y = new double[j][];
```

I perform some sort of operations on them, and want to return both of them as a result of the function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you *could* return an array of jagged arrays: `double[][][]`

```
public double[][][] GetData(int i, int j)
{
    double[][] x = new double[i][];
    double[][] y = new double[j][];

    return new [] {x, y};
}
```

but it may make more sense to define a class to give the results context.  If you return two arrays what do they mean?  Are they always in the same order?  By just returning an array you leave a lot for the consumer to learn about the meaning of the return type.  A class, on the other hand, would provide context:

```
public TwoArrays GetData(int i, int j)
{
    double[][] x = new double[i][];
    double[][] y = new double[j][];

    return new TwoArrays {X = x, Y = y};
}

public class TwoArrays
{
    public double[][] X  {get; set;}
    public double[][] Y  {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: So, should I define a class with 2 fields, each of them a jagged array, create a new object of that class in my function and reurn that object? Like public class MyClass { //fields }, then public static MyClass function(){ MyClass obj1 = new Myclass; //something; return obj1 }?

Comment: @Januszoff That would certainly make the purpose of the arrays much clearer - I've added that to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Tuples are a completely valid option as well.  Some folks don't like them as a matter of opinion, and they're NOT great options for public APIs, but they're useful without adding yet another class to your namespace.  You can go overboard with them, and four- and five-tuples exceed even my tolerance for them

```
        double[][] x = new double[i][];
        double[][] y = new double[j][];
        // Work your magic
        return new Tuple<double[][], double[][]>(x, y);
```

Item1 and Item2 will now be your double[][] arrays.